# Have Palestinian representatives ever offered any peace solutions in its negotiations with Israel?

Tags: israel, palestine

The question is quite simple as stated - have Palestinians or their representatives ever provided/brought a peace plan to the negotiation table? If they did, what was the plan? If they didn't, why?

All peace proposals **initiated by** PA, PLO, and HAMAS are welcome.

Comment: The Oslo accords?

Comment: Voting to close - Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and first do a search online. (I did a search for "Palestine peace proposal" and immediately came across two resources - [All the Times Israel Has Rejected Peace With Palestinians](https://theintercept.com/2023/11/28/israel-palestine-history-peace/) and [Israel has rejected every offer from Palestinians for a two-state solution](https://www.middleeasteye.net/opinion/israel-palestine-negotiation-idea-always-fiction)). Note that SEs are not discussion platforms.

Comment: @sfxedit After years of learning proposals from the West and Israel, I am yet waiting to see/hear a proposal from the most relevant player in this play - the Palestinians themselves.  I stay firm on my question, though you may choose to shut it down.

Comment: I've no issue with your Q itself as I am one of the few here who support the Palestinian right to self-determination and return of their land. It is how you have lazily asked the question here that irks me, without any effort from your part. Do remember that people here are offering their expertise and labour for free. If more and more people keep posting one and 2 line questions, answers for which are easily found online, many will just lose interest here as they aren't here to offer their free knowledge to spoonfeed people. Without them content quality will drop and Po.SE will lose its value

Comment: But yes, this SE is laxer than others and there are many other Q here similar to yours ...

Comment: @sfxedit I simply want to know the peace plan offered/brought by the Palestinians themselves, not those proposed by the bystanders, which they always find something rejectable.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It was brokered by the US, and not fully accepted by both sides at and after the signing. I am looking for a peace proposal provided by the Palestinians.

Comment: @r13 Note that down- and close- votes are just feedbacks for you to improve your posts. For example, I have already provided you 2 sources that answer your question. Please read that, and if it doesn't satisfy your curiosity, please edit your question and tell us why, and we'll vote to reopen your question.  (Please use the edit button freely, as many time as you want, to improve the quality of your question based on such feedbacks).

Comment: @sfxedit Your first link didn't mention any proposal "brought/prepared/offered by" the Palestinian, and your second source is an "opinion", neither answers my question - is there a peace proposal made by the Palestinian?

Comment: Please don't argue for the sake of arguing - 1st link - *In 1997, Khaled Mashal, then the top Hamas leader, offered a 30-year ceasefire to Israel* ... *In 2004, Sheik Ahmed Yassin, Hamas’s chief religious leader, called for a 10-year truce with Israel if it returned to its pre-1967 borders.* ... *The new Palestinian prime minister ... told Bush, “We are so concerned about stability and security in the area that we don’t mind having a Palestinian state in the 1967 border and offering a truce"* ... *... Ahmed Jabari, Hamas’s military chief, was reviewing a draft proposal for such a truce ...

Comment: @sfxedit Why don't you write the answer if you can back up your claims?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the Palestinians themselves". Apparently you don't consider PLO etc. as representative, so whom do you expect to have made those proposals and in what form? E.g. are you asking about a spontaneous street rally for peace?

Comment: @Fizz All peace proposals from PA, PLO, and HAMAS are welcome.

Comment: What would you consider a 'peace proposal'? IIRC the Palestinians have always had the option for peace on the table; the Jews must simply leave the territory, preferably dead, and there will be peace.

Comment: The only internationally recognized representative of the Palestinians is the Palestinian Authority. It is largely based of PLO - so they are not exactly independent things... more like the government vs. the ruling political party.

Comment: Palestinian representatives?? There is no unite representative for Palestinian. Hamas strongly (and rightly so, because of the history of Palestine from 1900-1948 and 1948-1967) believes that Israel must leave Palestine and that there is no other solution. Other representatives (servants of Israel and US) say let's forget the past (it doesn't matter how many Palestinians Israel has killed and occupied their land) and let take the path of peace. (And their situation is always getting worse).

Comment: @sfxedit You say: *I am one of the few here who support the Palestinian right to self-determination and return of their land* - this is a false claim: nearly everyone in the civilized world supports Palestinian self-determination, even most Israelis. What most people do not support is the Hamas' violent methods, calls for destruction of Israel, and Islamist theocracy.

Comment: @RogerV. Palestinian right to self-determination can be fulfilled with either the one-state or two-state solution. But the reality is that today's Israel doesn't accept either. Israeli right-wingers have assassinated every Israeli, PLO and Hamas leader who worked for a peaceful resolution. *Hamas' terrorism is a symptom, not the disease*. Hamas is just a mirror image of the right-wing in Israel who have managed to claw to power there. As long as either exist, no viable peace is possible. Those who shout about Hamas without recognizing this are just further suppressing the Palestinian cause.

Comment: @sfxedit that's a fairy tale, intended to justify your pre-existing biases, not a fact-based analysis

Comment: @sfxedit as I pointed today to someone who reasons like you - one could equally describe Netanyahu's rise and longevity, and increased power of Israeli right-wing by Hamas intrasergeance and Palestinian terrorism. Rabin, Barak, Olmert all offered peace and were kicked out of office as weak in fighting terrorism. Even Sharon wanted to withdraw from Gaza and WB. But Hamas treated every concession as a victory for its terrorist tactics, and unleashed more attacks.

Comment: @RogerV. 1. Khaled Mashal, then the top Hamas leader, offered a 30-year ceasefire to Israel. Israel did not respond — but did immediately try to assassinate Mashal in Jordan. 2. In 2004, Sheik Ahmed Yassin, Hamas’s chief religious leader, called for a 10-year truce with Israel if it returned to its pre-1967 borders. Israel assassinated him two months later. 3. Hamas’s military wing had become convinced that Palestinians should negotiate a long-term truce with Israel. On the same day Ahmed Jabari, Hamas’s military chief, was reviewing a draft proposal for such a truce, Israel assassinated him.

Comment: @sfxedit I discussed these proposals in my answer. They want to eat the cake and still have it. No one believes Hamas anymore - their time has passed.

Comment: @RogerV. Actions speaks louder than words. The pattern is clear among Israeli right-wingers - they assassinate every Israeli, PLO or Hamas leader who seeks a peaceful political resolution because they need Palestinian "terrorists" to look good themselves. The facts speak for themselves and Israel is running out of excuses to hide the facts that it is a brutal coloniser who has no intention of allowing the Palestinians to live in the territory Israel desires until the Palestinian become a minority in that region. .

Comment: @sfxedit I already answered to these arguments elsewhere: one can equally claim that Hamas led to the rise of Netanyahu, the assassinations, and the loss of faith in peace among Israelis: Hamas genocidal 1988 charter was adopted before Oslo, peace negotiations, recognition of Palestinians aspirations for statehood, Israeli withdrawal from most of the West Bank, Israeli withdrawal from Gaza - all that Israel received in exchange was  suicide bombings and rockets. You try to string the facts in order to get the conclusions that you desire, but this not an honest intellectual analysis.

Comment: @RogerV. You are saying the same thing I am  - Israeli-right needed Hamas for its politics of hate, to capture power. Note that Israel was supporting and funding Hamas even before Netanyahu. Hamas was propped up to divide PLO and discredit the Palestinians. And that did indeed help in creating further hate between Israelis and Palestinians which was harnessed by the Israeli-right and contributed to the rise of Netanyahu and other right-wingers in Israel. Netanyahu continues the same policy of his predecessors to keep funding Hamas and keep the hate festering.

Comment: @sfxedit no, we are saying opposite things: you blame Israel for the rise of Hamas, whereas I say that one can make the opposite argument - and there is more evidence to support it.

Comment: @RogerV. And I was pointing out how that argument is flawed - the fact is that the Israeli-right deliberately supported and funded Hamas. Hamas attacks Israelis and helps create a climate of fear and hatred in Israel which the right- needs to flourish. These religious fundamentalist in Israel do not support the 2-state solution as they want to capture all the land of the Palestinians, and they do not support a 1-state solution where Arabs will be the majority. Thus we see the pattern of Israeli settlements to capture more territory and violence to chase or kill Palestinians over the decades.

Comment: @sfxedit I don't see point continuing, since you clearly don't have grasp of the facts. Hamas genocidal charter dates back to 1988, Netanyahu's first prime-ministership was in 1996, and second in 2009. Whereas the rise of the Israeli extreme right is the development of the last decade. And nobody in the world, except Hamas-like extremists and the extreme left-wing, supports a one-state solution with Arab majority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oslo process**
It is not entirely clear what is meant in the question: [the peace process launched by the Oslo accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_peace_process#Timeline) is a two-sided venture, where both sides (Israel and the Palestinians, as represented by the Palestinian authority) contribute equally.

Israel has indeed made a few proposals intended at reaching the *final status agreement*, notably those by Ehud Barak and Ehud Olmert during the two respective premier-ministerships. The Palestinian side (Yasir Arafat and later Mahmoud Abbas) has rejected both, as they didn't go far enough in terms of the status of Jerusalem and the refugee return - that is they are more or less clear what their proposal would imply.
See [2000 Camp David Summit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Camp_David_Summit) and [Realignment plan: 2008 secret offer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realignment_plan#2008_secret_offer).

The sticking points in the negotiations are:

- *Borders:* Israel retreating to ["1967 borders" (i.e., 1949 armstice lines, also known as *Green line*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Line_(Israel)) vs. Israel keeping large West Bank settlements and compensating Palestinians by other territory.
- *Right of return:* the number of Palestinian refugees that would be allowed to return to Israel. Israel opposes the large number of refugees for demographic reasons, while Palestinians insist on the return of all refugees - note that [this number includes not only those who actually fled from the territory now controlled by Israel, but all their descendants.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_refugees)
- *Status of Jerusalem:* Palestinians want East Jerusalem to be the capital of the Palestinian state, while Israel insist on keeping control of the city and having free access to the [Western wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Wall). Note that the Palestinian shrines on the Temple mountain above the wall are run by [Jerusalem Waqf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Waqf).
- *Security guarantees* - the size and the permitted capacities of the Palestinian army, so that it does not pose danger to Israel.
- *Final status agreement:* Israel wants Palestinian assurances that the Peace agreement would be a final one, i.e. the Palestinians would not pose future territorial demands - the amounts to renouncing the claim to [all of the area "from the river to the sea"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_the_river_to_the_sea).

[**Arab peace initiative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Peace_Initiative)
There is also a proposal by the Arab league, which is acceptable to the Palestinians, but not to Israel. This one is somewhat informal, since most of the states promoting it do not have diplomatic ties with Israel, but they do offer full normalization in exchange for what is considered as *Palestinian parameters* in terms of borders, the right of return and the status of Jerusalem. It however signaled the Arab League members willingness to accept Israel's right to exist (e.g., the final status point outlines above.)

**Hamas' hudna**
[Hamas has floated the idea of a long-term truce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamas) - for 10 years and even for 100 years. However, unlike the proposals mentioned above, it was never an official decision by Hamas, but rather something mentioned in passing in speeches by Hamas officials, and hence deniable. These are also unacceptable to Israel, since they deny Israel diplomatic recognition, and since Hamas refuses to sign to the security and economic agreements achieved within the Oslo accords. On the other hand, this would mean recognition of Hamas as a representative of the Palestinian people, violating the internationally recognized status of the Palestinian Authority and various previous agreements.

Hamas offer was a classical case of proverbial eating the cake and still having it: it offers none of the points outlined above. Notably, Hamas and its supporters are vocal in gaining control of all of the territory between the Mediterranean and Jordan river.

[**Geneva Initiative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Initiative)
Finally, there was also Geneva peace initiative, where the representatives of the Israeli left signed a peace agreement with Palestinian representatives. It was mostly a symbolic gesture, since neither had the authority to officially represent their side.

**Remark**
What again comes out is that *"Palestinians"* are not a homogeneous group of people sharing the same views on peace, violence, justice, etc. Neither is it clear who has the authority to speak for them - Palestinian Authority, recognized by most of the world and the US, Arab League, as a representative of all Arabs, or Hamas, who enjoys some popularity and de facto controls and runs Gaza.

In this conditions, it is not clear whether any Palestinian representative is capable of accepting a peace offer - since the rival political groups may always claim that he *sold out* the Palestinian cause and that they can extract more from Israel by refusing to abide by the conditions of the agreement and/or resorting to more violence... while Israel would have already made concessions by reaching half-way to the peace offer. Indeed, [Hamas victory in 2006 legislative elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Palestinian_legislative_election) was largely seen as the consequence of Israel's withdrawal from Gaza.

Thus, the typical Israeli right's response to those claiming that Israel is not doing enough for peace is that there is no Palestinian partner to negotiate with, capable of making peace.

Comment: "what is considered as Palestinian parameters." Which are? Is this a reference to the Oslo points above, or to something different. It is hard to tell.

Comment: @ohwilleke I mean that the proposal is more favorable to Palestinians - pretty much on the same points that Israel couldn't concede in the Oslo context: the 1967 borders, right of return, east Jerusalem. It is still important, since it signaled that Arabs are willing to accept Israel's existence.